# Vectorized LUT classification using ArrayFire

Tags: c++, gpgpu, gpu, arrayfire

Is there a way to write a vectorized table lookup using ArrayFire?

I'm trying to implement a binary 2D pixel classifier using a 255x255 lookup table. This table contains the 2 channels value combinations [0,255] which should be classified: E.g.
 `channel[0] == 127 && channel[1] == 200` would be available for lookup as `lut[127][200] == True`.

The non-vectorized pseudo-code example:

```
for pixel in line  
    output[pixel] = LUT[ pixel[channel_0] ][ pixel[channel_1] ]
```

Possible approaches for ArrayFire:

- [Gfor loop]
  The following doesn't seem to be a valid syntax, so I'm not sure if this is altogether possible:

  `gfor(af::seq i, line.dims(0)) { classification(i) = lut(line(i)); }`
- [Custom CUDA kernel]
  Upload both the lookup table & the input line (possibly in segments) & distribute over blocks.
- others?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to specify how the variables are stored in your program and what you have tried so far.